# Including .svg images error

Tags: xetex, svg

Why this code doesn't work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=15mm,
  bindingoffset=2mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}

\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includesvg{example.svg}
\caption{Image created with Inkscape}\label{figura:2}
\vspace{7pt}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

TexWorks 0.61 sends this error:

```
("C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\microtype\mt-cmr.c
    fg")
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    \@includesvg ...extracttrue \fi \ifnum \pdfstrcmp 
                                                      {\pdffilemoddate {\SVG@in@...
    l.23 \includesvg{example.svg}

?
```

I'm compiling in XeLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX

Comment: Hi, welcome. The reason for my edit is that the linebreaks in an error message have meaning, so preserving them are sometimes essential for properly understanding the error. For *undefined control sequence* errors, the last control sequence before the linebreak is the one that triggered the error. Just to doublecheck, is it correct that `\pdfstrcmp` is the last one before the linebreak?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/OoN6Nuq.png

Comment: So, "yes", in other words. It works if you use `pdflatex` with `--shell-escape` enabled (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82699/how-to-enable-shell-escape-in-texworks), I think some primitives like `\pdfstrcmp` are not defined by XeLaTeX (they have different names), which is why it doesn't work, but someone else needs to confirm that.

Comment: Basically same thing as http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126706/586 Doesn't seem like there's any solutions for XeLaTeX, though I may be wrong.