# filemoddate in xetex

Tags: xetex, psfrag, pstool

I  compile the below file:

```
%my main file is named `document .tex`.
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[crop=pdfcrop,process=all]{pstool}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas_4.ttf}
\begin{document}
    سلام و درود بر شما
\begin{latin}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\psfragfig*[width=0.6\linewidth]{02}{\color{blue}
\psfrag{TMP1}{5}%
\psfrag{TMP2}{$t$}
}
\end{figure}
\end{latin}
 ادامه‌ی متن
\end{document}
```

With   `xelatex --shell-escape`  compile and  this `output`:

[image]

And with this `eror`:

```
Package filemod Error: Required command \pdffilemoddate is not defined!. ...date\space is not defined!}{\filemod@help}
As you can see, the labels can not replacement properly.
```

But we know the pstool package use the `catchfile,color,ifpdf,ifplatform,filemod,graphicx,psfrag,shellesc,suffix,trimspaces,xkeyval` and `expl3` packages  too. At the begining of the `filemod` package .pdf we read: This package will work with `LATEX` and `plain ε-TEX` as long `pdf(LA)TEX` (in PDF or DVI mode) or `Lua(LA)TEX` is used. `XETEX` is not supported because it does not provide `\pdffilemoddate`. why? Who smells rat?:))
can this define the `\pdffilemoddate` command (or the same command) in `xetex engine`  too?
[My eps file is here.](http://s6.picofile.com/d/8383517000/c92def0f-ff3e-4dca-85a4-03798e7ae168/02.eps)
Thanks.

**Second edit about David's advice:**
I completely update my texlive. My above pstools error has been fixed.
But my problem is still persist.
This is [my log file](https://easyupload.io/pmkx5o) and [my font](http://s6.picofile.com/d/8383703592/f259f0d1-e916-4ff9-9147-592177eb9250/Yas_4.ttf).
**Compile With**: `xelatex --shell-escape %.tex`
**Editor**: `TeX studio`

**Third edit:**
With `xelatex -shell-escape` I have the below warning:

```
No file "02.tex" or "02-psfrag.tex" can be found that may contain macros for "02.eps".
```

My eps file name is  `02.eps` and I don't have  `02.tex` file or `02-psfrag.tex`  in my folder.
The above warning with pdflatex -shell-escape (without persian script and xepersian package)  is existing too. But  `02.pdf` file at the below
would add to my folder.

[image]

If I add the above file (02.pdf) to my folder,  my `xelatex's compile` will have a correct  output.
My question clearly is:
**why with xelatex -shell-escape processing, 02.pdf not formed?**
 This is [my log file dropbox link](http://dropbox.com/s/h5ydlehs9bz7aje/document.log?dl=0%20%E2%80%93).

Comment: @Fractal  Thanks. May minimal code is above and i need to use \psfragfig command.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Related: https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/feature-requests/16, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126706/203621.

Comment: @Fractal As Khaled Hosny's told, can you use \pdf@strcmp from pdftexcmds package, for handle engine differences on my minimal file?

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea. Maybe a better user will answer this for you.

Comment: @Fractal Thanks again.

Comment: it isn't clear what you mean by "why? Who smells rat"  `\(pdf)filemoddate` is a tex extension added to pdftex and it simply was not added to xetex until last year.

Comment: @David Carlisle I thought it's related to xetex structure. Thanks again.

Comment: You seem to have installed a texlive 2019 in a 2018 folder - which is rather confusing. And you shouldn't put files for download on sites using arabic (or whatever buttons) - that makes it quite difficult to people which can't read the script. Beside this: I don't think that psfrag/pstool currently work with xelatex, you should prepare your graphics with latex or pdflatex instead and then include them.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks for your advice. but i need to use persian script for run in xelatex (not pdflatex) engine. They are not specific words. there just for greeting and a continuation of the text. But as you told It seams to psfrag/pstool packages isn't set with xelatex. Thanks again.

Comment: sure but you don't need persian in your eps - that is simply a chemical formula, so you can create it with latex.

Comment: Thanks again. I have a lot of persian script in my file. So I cant compile with pdflatex. For example  this error :Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or(fontspec) LuaTeX. \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}

Comment: I changed the font to Amiri and do not get any error about filemoddate, I do get `Package pstool Warning: No file "02.tex" or "02-psfrag.tex"`  as I don't have those. Please add your log file to the question or make it directly available. Your "log" link goes to a web page with a lot of buttons and adverts that I would not want to trust even if I could read the text

Comment: @David Carlisle I add my log file at the end of my question. with new version of texlive 2019 I have your same error and I dont get any error about filemoddate. But my output is still wrong. with pdflatex -shell-escape (without persian script and xepersian package) I have a pdf image (in addition to output document.pdf ) but I dont have it with xelatex --shell-escape. Thanks again.

Comment: @SH.Madadpour no as I said before I am not going to click on any links on a web page that is full of links and advert images in a language that I can not read.

Comment: @David Carlisle Excuse me. This is my file dropbox link .
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h5ydlehs9bz7aje/document.log?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

`\filemoddate` was added to xetex in the 2019 release, so if you have an up to date system the example runs without error (although I tested with a different font and eps file).

It may be possible to avoid the use of filemod on older systems, but updating is probably easiest.

On older systems it probably works to define it to return a fixed date, so

```
\providecommand\pdffilemoddate[1]{D:20200101111927Z}
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. let me update my texlive as soon as and test it.

Comment: My problem is still persist. Please see me second edit. Thanks